# Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file

Tags: android, logcat

I have 2 errors in logcat.

```
Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 

04-11 10:58:13.837: E/SELinux(10101): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_SGH-I337M_4.3_0022
```

It's not fatal, my app seems to be fine.

Any idea what is the cause, and how do I fix it? Just can have Error Logs in my app!

Comment: Seeing the same thing recently...

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23976400/3499115

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to get rid of those messages.  But they do prevent the Android NDK `ndk-gdb` script from working.  I found this question while searching for a way to get the debugger working after getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not setup network redirection to gdbserver?
       Maybe using --port=<port> to use a different TCP port might help?
```

This seems to be an issue with some phones - possibly Samsung phones, or at least the one that I am working with is a Samsung Galaxy Note 2.  Certain commands (such as `run-as`) come with these selinux warning messages in stderr output.

The `ndk-gdb` script parses output from shell commands run on a device to determine facts like the path of the data directory for the package that it is debugging.  The selinux messages interfere with that collection.  To fix that problem, edit `$NDK_HOME/ndk-gdb` and make this change:

```
diff --git a/ndk-gdb b/ndk-gdb
index 537808e..c8561e5 100755
--- a/ndk-gdb
+++ b/ndk-gdb
@@ -620,7 +620,7 @@ else
 fi

 # Find the <dataDir> of the package on the device
-adb_var_shell2 DATA_DIR run-as $PACKAGE_NAME /system/bin/sh -c pwd
+adb_var_shell DATA_DIR "run-as $PACKAGE_NAME /system/bin/sh -c pwd 2>/dev/null"
 if [ $? != 0 -o -z "$DATA_DIR" ] ; then
     echo "ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that"
     echo "       your installed application is debuggable?"
```